# Util function to rotate a Map?

Tags: java, collections

Is there any function in a Util libary (commonsXXX or something else) that can rotate a Map.

By rotating I mean I have a `Map<User,Set<Permission>>` that should be "rotated" to `Map<Permission,Set<User>>`?

I know it is not hard to implement, but using a common existing library seems to be better in terms of "don't invent the wheel twice".

Comment: Have you considered introducing a UserPermission class that sits between the many-to-many relationship? You could easily iterate over all your UserPermissions and create the two multimaps with the structure you want.

Comment: @Javid Jamae: not so complicated, the maps must even not been connected. the rotated one can be a unconnected copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to do the same thing as what you describe, I used a multimap from commons-collections and wrote my own inverse function. (That was at least 3 years ago, using jdk1.4, so guava wasn't an option.)

But if you changed your original map to a SetMultimap (I prefer multimaps anyway when mapping keys to collections of values, since they make inserting values easier), then you could use [com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.invertFrom](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html):

```
public static <K,V,M extends Multimap<K,V>> M invertFrom(Multimap<? extends V,? extends K> source,
                                         M dest)

Copies each key-value mapping in source into dest, with its key and value reversed.

Parameters:
    source - any multimap
    dest - the multimap to copy into; usually empty
Returns:
    dest
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find this in the common libraries either, so here is my implementation:

```
public static <K, V> Map<V, Set<K>> invertMapToSet(Map<K, ? extends Set<V>> ksToVs) {
    Map<V, Set<K>> vsToKs = new HashMap<V, Set<K>>();
    for (Entry<K, ? extends Set<V>> kToVs : ksToVs.entrySet()) {
        for (V v : kToVs.getValue()) {
            Set<K> ks = vsToKs.get(v);
            if (ks == null) {
                ks = new HashSet<K>();
                vsToKs.put(v, ks);
            }
            ks.add(kToVs.getKey());
        }
    }
    return vsToKs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Guava's [`BiMap.inverse()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html). Otherwise you can use [`MapUtils.invertMap()`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/MapUtils.html).

You probably thought of this, but reversing a map would require keys as well as values to be unique.

**EDIT** On a closer look, I'm pretty sure no publically available component will do *that* for you. I read the question as invert `Map<A,B>` to `Map<B,A>`.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this will do. `inverse()` will return `Map<Set<Permission>,User>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's quite unlikely you'll find something like that in some utility library.

I'm saying that because it's not a simple inversion you're looking for, but you'd also need to unpack the `Permission` objects from the original map values.